# CSS - Landscape html page in print slips in other page

Tags: html, css, printing

I made a simple page, where I want some page break and the pages in landscape for print. The problem is, that all the pages are slipping in the previous page.
Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .break {
            page-break-after: always;
        }
        .page {
            width: 29.7cm;
            height: 21cm;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        @media print {
            .container {
                 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
                 -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
                 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page break container">
    Lorem ipsum (...) turpis.
    </div>
    <div class="page break container">
    Nulla sagittis (...) lectus.
    </div>
    <div class="page container">
    Donec pharetra (...) Curae;
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the result in print preview looks like this: [image]

I tried to modify the width and height and some others things, but the only difference is the position where the text is drawn on the preview.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried forcing page-vreak through this:

```
@media print {
.break {page-break-after: always;}
}
```

(also specify landscape in your print CSS, not by rotating it, like this:

```
@media print{@page {size: landscape}}
```

)
?

Comment: Tried it, still the same.

Comment: With the edit it works great. It looks good also in IE, it has only a little problem, but that I can figure it out. Thank you!